# Filter query by ID

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve all the product information, filtering by product category id. The result should be hundreds of products but only returns 5 items. Whats wrong with my query?

```
SELECT product.id_product, 
product.reference,  
product.price,
product.active, 
product.quantity,  
product.id_category_default, 
lang.name AS product_name, 
lang.description, 
lang.link_rewrite AS product_link_rewrite,  
category.name AS category_name, 
category.link_rewrite AS category_link_rewrite, 
image.id_image, 
product.id_manufacturer, 
discount.reduction, 
manufacturer.name AS manufacturer_name 
FROM ps_product product 
LEFT JOIN ps_specific_price discount ON discount.id_product=product.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang lang ON lang.id_product=product.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang category ON category.id_category=product.id_category_default 
LEFT JOIN ps_image image ON image.id_product=product.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_manufacturer manufacturer ON manufacturer.id_manufacturer=product.id_manufacturer
WHERE product.active=1 
AND product.quantity>=1 
AND product.id_category_default IN 
(
  4,5,6,65,66,90,91,53,54,48,49,50,55,62,67,68,71,19,82,88,89,87,22,24,26,74,
  76,77,28,78,79,97,98,99,93,96,35,36,38,39,100
)
GROUP BY product.id_product ASC
```

Comment: Why are you performing a group by without an aggregate?  Perhaps you mean `ORDER BY`.  (in other words... Do you get the desired results if you eliminate the group by?)  I'm surprised you don't get a syntax error with `ASC` at the end of a group by.  How mySQL extends of the group by clause may be causing your problem

Comment: Changed to ORDER BY, same results...Another sugestion? Thanks..

Comment: Then expected results are inaccurate would be my guess run `select count(*) from ps_product product WHERE product.active=1 
AND product.quantity>=1 
AND product.id_category_default IN 
(
  4,5,6,65,66,90,91,53,54,48,49,50,55,62,67,68,71,19,82,88,89,87,22,24,26,74,
  76,77,28,78,79,97,98,99,93,96,35,36,38,39,100
);`  if the count matches the row count of your query then expected results are incorrect.  If they differ.... I just don't see how that's possible...  Can you provide a product whose active is 1 quantity is >=1 and whose ID_Category_Default is in your list, but not in results?

Comment: Put another way if you eliminate active and quantity from the where clause do you get the 100's your looking for?

Comment: No, still the 5 results...I think the product.id_category_default association is causing the problem, but i can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something as simple as:

`GROUP BY product.id_product ASC` 
needs to be:
`ORDER BY product.id_product ASC`

mySQL extends the group by clause so that any columns not in the group by may get an indeterminate value.

[If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns.  ... The server is free to choose any value from each group, so ***unless they are the same***, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Options:

- change group by to order by
- add all columns to the group by
- don't use group by at all.